# AWS Lambda using Python, get .json file data from S3 Bucket and put it into DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, amazon-dynamodb

This is the code I've made, and seemingly got the best result so far. I still get errors, but I got my best result so far with this.

I need to read three things from the .json file, which is ID, Name and Country using Python.

```
import json
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

table = dynamodb.Table('valid_cities')



def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    print(bucket)
    
    json_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    print(json_file_name)
    
    json_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=json_file_name)
    print(json_object)
    
    file_reader = json_object['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")
    print(file_reader)
    
    jsonDict = json.loads(file_reader)
    print(jsonDict)
    

    table.put_item(Item={'id':{'N':id},'name':{'S':name},'country':{'S':country}})
```

I've gotten this far, it reads the json file in the S3 bucket, and processes it. Now I'm being met with an error that states the following:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "name 'name' is not defined",
  "errorType": "NameError",
  "requestId": "c2f72151-9591-4f35-909b-6b7876b4253a",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 28, in lambda_handler\n    table.put_item(Item={'id':{'N':id},'name':{'S':name},'country':{'S':country}})\n"
  ]
```

This is a piece of the sample data in the citylist.json file:

```
{
    "city_list":[
        {
            "id": 6951112,
            "name": "Somerset West",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ZA",
            "coord": {
                "lon": 18.821131,
                "lat": -34.084011
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3358975,
            "name": "Yzerfontein",
            "state": "",
            "country": "ZA",
            "coord": {
                "lon": 18.16157,
                "lat": -33.344379
            }
        }
]
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but the error is quite clear: on your last line you are using `name` and `country`, which you haven't defined anywhere... Btw also the `id` you've used there - not sure it gives what you think it gives.

Comment: Also, the JSON appears to include multiple cities but your code is only attempting to write one item to DynamoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Anon Coward suggested but last line can be left plain:

```
import json
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('valid_cities')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    json_file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    json_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=json_file_name)
    jsonDict = json.load(json_object['Body'])
    
    for city in jsonDict['city_list']:
        table.put_item(Item={'id': city['id'],'name': city['name'],'country':city['country']})
```